# Regular expression to match the string representation of non ascii characters \u0000-\u007F from a string and replace with empty string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, hex, pattern-matching

I am getting hexadecimal representation of unicode characters in my string and want to replace that with empty string. More specifically, trying to match all values within \u0000-\u007F in a string using regex to replace it with empty string with C#.

**Example 1:**

InputString: "\u007FTestString"

ExpectedResult: TestString

**Example 2:**

InputString: "\u007FTestString\U0000"

ExpectedResult: TestString

My current solution does

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testString))
            {
                return Regex.Replace(testString, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);
            }
```

does not match the hexadecimal representation of the non-ascii character. How do i get it to match the \u0000-\u007F in the string ?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For matching literally try something like [`\\[uU]00[0-7][0-9A-F]`](https://regex101.com/r/L9JGKs/2)

Comment: Isn't `\u0000-\u007F` exactly the range of ASCII characters? Did you perhaps intend to replace `\u0080-\uFFFF`?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(@"\u007FTestString\U0000", @"\\[uU]00[0-7][0-9A-Fa-f] ", "")`. Note your input strings must be declared as verbatim string literals.

Comment: consider the security implication. In general you should never remove invalid characters (but one could/should replace them with a replacement character (e.g. `?`). So: user know something go wrong and they fix their side, and you do not have security problems: some part of the program/stack see different things (so you may allocate shorted buffer for a longer string, etc., or you can impersonate other accounts). In short: do not do it, but if you are generating the data (and you cannot correct upstream).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. This worked 

Regex.Replace(@"\u007FTestString", @"\\[uU]00[0-7][0-9A-Fa-f]", "");

but why does it not work when i do the following: 

string inputString = "\u007FTestString";
Regex.Replace(@inputString, @"\\[uU]00[0-7][0-9A-Fa-f]", "");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var result = Regex.Replace(@"\u007FTestString\U0000", @"\\[uU]00[0-7][0-9A-Fa-f]", "");
```

The `@"..."` verbatim string literal syntax is required to make all backslashes literal characters that do not form any string escape sequences.

*Pattern details*:

- `\\` - a backslash
- `[uU]` - `u` or `U`
- `00` - two zeros
- `[0-7]` - a digit from zero to seven
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]` - an ASCII hex digit char.

Comment: This works but my input string is coming as a input parameter of a method so when i do

Regex.Replace(@inputString, @"\[uU]00[0-7][0-9A-Fa-f]", "") - it's not matching the unicode's hexadecimal representation.

Comment: @Utsab Then use `var result = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[\p{C}-\r\n\t]+", "");`